# Recommendations for distributed calculations of Groebner Bases

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, computer-algebra, groebner-bases

There are many computer algebra systems available which can compute a Groebner basis, including:

- Mathematica
- Singular
- Macaulay2
- Magma
- Maple
- CoCoA

However (please correct me if I've missed something) they do not support distributed computing when doing so.  Ideally a good distributed computing implementation would allow spreading both the cpu and memory usage across many machines, allowing computing results not otherwise possible.

It is not hard to find papers discussing work towards parallel or fully distributed computation of Groebner bases. But they often do not share their code, and I am curious as to why nothing has made it into the more established mathematical software.  Is this just a really difficult computing problem that is currently not solved? Or, I'm hoping, have I just overlooked some great tools available to the community?

What tools are recommended for distributed calculations of Groebner Bases?

(NOTE: there is an attempt towards parallel computation in Macaulay2, [ThreadedGB](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.19/share/doc/Macaulay2/ThreadedGB/html/index.html), but unless I'm misunderstanding, it does not support distributing across multiple computers. Also, the researchers implementing it seemed to be more interested in investigating the "lineage" of calculations, which seems to take up a lot of memory and runs quite slowly.  Maybe I'm not setting something up correctly, but I had better luck with a single cpu instance of Singular.)